# is autopostback available in jQuery or Ajax

Tags: javascript, entities

for Drupal 6 sites. I know that autopostback is an ASP.NET piece of functionality. Is there something similar that I can apply in Drupal 6. I want to apply autopostback to a drop-down select list in a view.

All I have found so far is this piece of code:

document.getElementById('mytextbox').AutoPostBack = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id="autosubmit" name="autosubmit" class="autosubmit">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".autosubmit").each(function (index) {
    $(this).change(function () {
      // write your custom trigger here.
    })
  });
});
```